# Union query distinct on one column

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, union, coalesce

I would like results from the second query to override results from the first query:

```
SELECT "panel_restaurants_restaurant"."id",
       "panel_restaurants_restaurant"."name",
       "panel_restaurants_restaurant"."logo",
       "panel_restaurants_restaurantfeatures"."currency" AS "currency",
       ST_DistanceSphere(location, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0.0 0.0)',4326)) AS "distance",
       "panel_meals_meal"."id" AS "meal_id",
       "panel_meals_meal"."status" AS "meal_status",
       "panel_meals_meal"."available_count" AS "available_dishes",
       "panel_meals_meal"."discount_price" AS "discount_price",
       "panel_meals_meal"."normal_price" AS "normal_price",
       "panel_meals_meal"."collection_from" AS "pickup_from",
       "panel_meals_meal"."collection_to" AS "pickup_to",
       "panel_meals_meal"."description" AS "meal_description"
FROM "panel_restaurants_restaurant"
INNER JOIN "panel_restaurants_restaurantfeatures" ON (
    "panel_restaurants_restaurantfeatures"."restaurant_id" = "panel_restaurants_restaurant"."id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "panel_meals_meal" ON ("panel_restaurants_restaurant"."id" = "panel_meals_meal"."restaurant_id"
                AND "panel_meals_meal"."status" = 0
                AND (
                ("panel_meals_meal"."collection_from" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Warsaw')::date = DATE 'today' OR
                ("panel_meals_meal"."collection_from" AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Warsaw')::date = DATE 'tomorrow'
                )
                AND "panel_meals_meal"."collection_to" > '2017-07-29 19:33:47.992075+00:00'
                AND "panel_meals_meal"."available_count" > 0)
WHERE "panel_restaurants_restaurant"."status" = 2
UNION
SELECT "panel_restaurants_restaurant"."id",
       "panel_restaurants_restaurant"."name",
       "panel_restaurants_restaurant"."logo",
       "panel_restaurants_restaurantfeatures"."currency" AS "currency",
       ST_DistanceSphere(location, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(0.0 0.0)',4326)) AS "distance",
       "panel_meals_meal"."id" AS "meal_id",
       "panel_meals_meal"."status" AS "meal_status",
       "panel_meals_meal"."initial_count" AS "available_dishes",
       "panel_meals_meal"."discount_price" AS "discount_price",
       "panel_meals_meal"."normal_price" AS "normal_price",
       "panel_meals_meal"."collection_from" AS "pickup_from",
       "panel_meals_meal"."collection_to" AS "pickup_to",
       "panel_meals_meal"."description" AS "meal_description"
FROM "panel_restaurants_restaurant"
INNER JOIN "panel_restaurants_restaurantfeatures" ON (
       "panel_restaurants_restaurantfeatures"."restaurant_id" = "panel_restaurants_restaurant"."id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "panel_meals_meal" ON (
    "panel_restaurants_restaurant"."id" = "panel_meals_meal"."restaurant_id" AND
    "panel_meals_meal"."status" = 0)
INNER JOIN "panel_meals_mealrepeater" ON (
    "panel_meals_mealrepeater"."meal_id" = "panel_meals_meal"."id")
WHERE "panel_restaurants_restaurant"."status" = 2    AND "panel_meals_mealrepeater"."saturday" = true
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

For example - the first query may return nulls for what comes from the `panel_meals_meal` table, but the second one will return something - in that situation I will have the same values for `id`, `name`, `logo`, `currency`, `distance` and different values (nulls returned from the first query, and `something` from the other one) for all the other ones.

So the question is - how do I make this `UNION` distinct on a certain range of columns (actually only one would suffice - `id`)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do what you want by means of a `FULL OUTER JOIN` instead of a `UNION`, and use `COALESCE` to your advantage.

I simplify your scenario to concentrate on the `FULL OUTER JOIN` part:

This are the tables (think of them as the *result* of your *first* `SELECT` before whe `UNION`, and the *second* `SELECT` after said `UNION`):

```
CREATE TABLE table_a
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    logo TEXT
) ;
CREATE TABLE table_b
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    logo TEXT
) ;
```

These are the data we have in them:

```
INSERT INTO 
   table_a
   (id, name, logo)
VALUES
   (1, 'Name1-A', 'Logo1-A'),
   (2, NULL, NULL),
   (3, 'Name3-A', NULL),
   (4, NULL, 'Logo4-A'),
   (5, 'Name5-only-in-A', NULL);

INSERT INTO 
   table_b
   (id, name, logo)
VALUES
   (1, 'Name1-B', 'Logo1-B'),
   (2, 'Name2-B', NULL),
   (3, 'Name3-B', 'Logo3-B'),
   (4, 'Name4-B', 'Logo4-B'),
   (6, 'Name6-only-in-B', 'Logo6-B');
```

The query you're looking for is done by *joining* in such a way that you retrieve all the rows from both `table_a` and `table_b`. Then, you use:

```
SELECT
    id, 
    COALESCE(a.name, b.name) AS name,
    COALESCE(a.logo, b.logo) AS logo
FROM
    table_a AS a
    FULL OUTER JOIN table_b AS b USING(id) 
ORDER BY
    id ;
```

```
id | name            | logo   
-: | :-------------- | :------
 1 | Name1-A         | Logo1-A
 2 | Name2-B         | null   
 3 | Name3-A         | Logo3-B
 4 | Name4-B         | Logo4-A
 5 | Name5-only-in-A | null   
 6 | Name6-only-in-B | Logo6-B
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=2b268056773d50e7feca907dad7b66cb)*

---

In your case, substitute `table_a AS a` by your full first `(SELECT ...) AS a`, and the same for `b`. I've assumed `id` are your primary keys.

References:

- [`FULL OUTER JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp)
- [`COALESCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL)
- [The FROM Clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) (look for `USING`)

Comment: It kind of works, but it uncovered another unexpected behavior. Now, if both selects return data then the result contains duplicates :(

Comment: No, with this scenario, they don't; that's taken care of by the `JOIN ... USING(id)`.  Look at the example, you do not have any duplicates for `id`, even if some of them are in both tables.

Comment: I don't know, maybe that's because you're using two separate tables in your example and I'm selecting from the same, but my result set contains duplicates.

Comment: In your original query it is expected to have *duplicate id values*, because `UNION` removes duplicates from *whole rows*. This is not the case when you `JOIN`. Take a look at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=fd0f1b260acada248c50eb93fbd988ea)* and make sure you understand the difference between the two queries.

Comment: I understand the difference, but my understanding doesn't affect the result set. See for yourself: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvXY9o8myEVmhc8z8IFOdcUClj5MlQ <- I did as you advised, so I've put my first query in place of the `table_a AS` expressions and did the same for the other one.

Comment: Result when running the first query: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AvXY9o8myEVmhc80D3Av7i0b7Fnhwg and the result of the second one: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AvXY9o8myEVmhc81xiV99s1WvL38Ow

Comment: If you get more than one `id`, this means that your original `SELECT` *already* give out more than one `id`. Check just one of them. You have more than one meal per restaurant... decide *which one* you actually want to report (for instant, you can `SELECT min(meal_id) GROUP BY id`). If you want to report more than one, and still do the joins, then `JOIN USING(id, meal_id)` will do the job.

Comment: You wrote your comment faster than I could write mine ;-)

Comment: Maybe these are not `NULLs`  but empty strings`''`, which *are not the same thing*. If that were the case, change  COALESCE(a.logo, b.logo) to `COALESCE(NULLIF(a.logo, ''), NULLIF(b.logo, '')` and the same for all columns.

Comment: It was my fault (forgot to use `COALESCE`), but there's another issue. Result after `JOIN USING(id, meal_id)` -> https://1drv.ms/i/s!AvXY9o8myEVmhc825KyQsMWpscgNcA <- as you can see the `niemiecka znizka` restaurant appears two times and once without `meal_id`, so that's basically the same situation I had initially :(. Just so you know what's in my topmost select statement: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AvXY9o8myEVmhc83Qsj8gv1zBB2zOQ (it's the same if I don't use `COALESCE` on meal_id column).

Comment: Ufff... Using `ON a.id = b.id AND (a.meal_id = b.meal_id OR a.meal_id IS NULL)` instead of `USING(id, meal_id)` solved the duplicates problem. Since you put me on the correct track, I'm accepting your answer :)

Comment: UNION is a lot "cheaper" operation than FULL OUTER JOIN

Answer (score 3):

Using [`DISTINCT ON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT), e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (maintenance_task_id)
  maintenance_task_id,
  execution_count
FROM (
  SELECT
    id maintenance_task_id,
    0 execution_count
  FROM maintenance_task
  UNION
  SELECT
    mte1.maintenance_task_id,
    count(*) execution_count
  FROM maintenance_task_execution mte1
  WHERE
    mte1.ended_at IS NULL
  GROUP BY mte1.maintenance_task_id
) AS t
ORDER BY
  maintenance_task_id,
  execution_count DESC
```

In this query:

1. `UNION` combines results of two queries.
2. `DISTINCT ON` picks one row from the top (based on the `ORDER BY`) for each unique `maintenance_task_id` value.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar by using a [WITH query/CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):

```
WITH override_query AS (SELECT * FROM blah_blah JOIN blah_blah [etc]),
     first_query AS (SELECT * FROM blah_blah JOIN blah_bluh [etc]
                    WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM override_query))
TABLE first_query UNION TABLE override_query
```